# GRUB messed up after plugging in external hard drive

Tags: grub2

I connected an external hard drive in which I have a dual boot of Win 7 and Ubuntu on my Ubuntu laptop to transfer some files. Now when I boot my laptop, it shows GRUB with the partitions from the external hard drive even though the latter is not connected to the computer. Obviously if I try to load some of the partitions from the external disk it fails.

How can I repair my MBR?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this using:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you updated the Ubuntu on the external hard drive using your laptop. The easiest way to fix this is to select the Ubuntu (the one installed in your laptop) and start your laptop with Ubuntu. Then run Update Manager. Once grub is updated, the external partitions will no longer show up. **(Perform this while the external hard drive is not connected to the laptop).**